# Huge integer file sorting in python

Tags: python

I want to create a file (size more than 2 GB) of integers (more than 64 bit each) and sort the file efficiently.

Comment: I suggest an idea:  Use a machine with lots of memory, load the file, sort it, write the result.

Comment: **Duplicate** of [merge sorted files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1001569/448474)

Answer (score 2):

1) Divide it to so big files that can be effectively sorted in the memory.
2) Merge those sorted files together into one file.

Details you find in answer [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1001625/448474)] which uses module `heapq` function `merge`.

Better is to use half of memory then to risk swapping.

I do not see anything wrong on this question. It is only a simple example of principle of the problem.

Comment: What's wrong with the question is that the OP didn't even bother to search the web or SO for ways to do this, but instead simply posted his or her [homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074541/sorting-arbitrary-size-integers) for us to solve.

Comment: heapq function merge is not merging the files in sorted order. I want that merged file should be sorted.

Comment: Did you read anything? "merge -- Merge multiple sorted inputs into a single sorted output." It works for me.